# What does "0" mean in the owner and group permission lists of a file/folder?

Tags: permissions, security

The question is in the title. What does the number 0 signify?

Comment: Where are you seeing it? What it means depends on exactly where you see it.

Comment: @derobert on CentOS 6.3

Comment: In the output of what command are you seeing it? Or as the argument to which? E.g., my `ls -l` prints permissions symbolically, and doesn't print 0. But its also not really a "list", so I'm at a loss as to where you're seeing this.

Answer (score 5):

That it belongs to user/group with ID `0`. That would be `root` (see `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`).

Comment: Note that on some systems (most notably the *BSDs) the group with the numerical id 0 is called `wheel`, not `root`.

Answer (score 0):

0=no rights for owner/group (quite unusual).